# How to display arrays in void function

Tags: c++, arrays, for-loop, void, minesweeper

I'm trying to write a program to create a simple Minesweeper game and I'm not sure what is causing the program to just put out a blank line, but my intentions is to print the chart of numbers for a minesweeper game. The program compiles just fine even though there is an error in running the program before receiving a line which says,

> sh: pause: command not found

The program uses void functions and I'm not sure how to define a variable that points to each square on the board.
I'm hoping someone can help me find out where the mistake is in this code that is causing the program to function so strangely.

C++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <time.h>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

// Global Constants
const int MAX_ROWS = 10;
const int MAX_COLUMNS = 10;
const int EMPTY_SQUARE_DIGIT = 0;
const char EMPTY_SQUARE_SYMBOL = '_'; 
const int BOMB_DIGIT = -1;
const char BOMB_SYMBOL = '#';
char currentCell = 0;

// Function Prototypes
void fillTheGameBoard(int board[MAX_ROWS][MAX_COLUMNS]);
void displayTheGameBoard(int board[MAX_ROWS][MAX_COLUMNS]);
void insertTheMineClues(int board[MAX_ROWS][MAX_COLUMNS]);
void incrementTheNeighborSquares(int board[MAX_ROWS][MAX_COLUMNS], int row, int column);


// ############################################
int main(void)
{
int gameBoard[MAX_ROWS][MAX_COLUMNS];

srand(time(NULL));

fillTheGameBoard(gameBoard);

insertTheMineClues(gameBoard);

displayTheGameBoard(gameBoard);

system("pause");

return 0;
} // End main


// ############################################
void fillTheGameBoard(int board[MAX_ROWS][MAX_COLUMNS])
{
   for (int row = 0; row < MAX_ROWS; row++)
   {
      if ( (row >= 0) && (row < MAX_ROWS) )
      {
      for (int column = 0; column < MAX_COLUMNS; column++)
      {
         if (rand() % (MAX_ROWS - 3) == 0)
         {
            currentCell = BOMB_DIGIT;
         }
         else
         {
            currentCell = EMPTY_SQUARE_DIGIT;
         }
      }
      }
   }                    
} // End fillTheGameBoard


// ############################################
void displayTheGameBoard(int board[MAX_ROWS][MAX_COLUMNS])
{
   for (int row = 0; row < MAX_ROWS; row++)
   {
      if ( (row >= 0) && (row < MAX_ROWS) )
      {
      for (int column = 0; column < MAX_COLUMNS; column++)
      {
         if (currentCell == BOMB_DIGIT)
         {
            cout << BOMB_SYMBOL;
         }
         else if (currentCell == EMPTY_SQUARE_DIGIT)
         {
            cout << EMPTY_SQUARE_SYMBOL;
         }
         else
         {
            cout << currentCell;
         }
      }
      }
   }  
} // End displayTheGameBoard


// ############################################
void insertTheMineClues(int board[MAX_ROWS][MAX_COLUMNS])
{
     for (int row = 0; row < MAX_ROWS; row++)
      {
        if ( (row >= 0) && (row < MAX_ROWS) )
         {
         for (int column = 0; column < MAX_COLUMNS; column++)
            {
               if (currentCell == BOMB_DIGIT)
                  {
                     incrementTheNeighborSquares(board, row, column);
                  }
            }
         }   
      }               

} // End insertTheMineClues


// ############################################
// The function definition below is finished.  Make no changes to it.
void incrementTheNeighborSquares(int board[MAX_ROWS][MAX_COLUMNS], int bombRow, int bombColumn)
{
for (int row = bombRow - 1; row <= bombRow + 1; row++)
   {
   if ( (row >= 0) && (row < MAX_ROWS) )     
      {   
      for (int column = bombColumn - 1; column <= bombColumn + 1; column++)
         {
         if ( (column >= 0) && (column < MAX_COLUMNS) && (board[row][column] != BOMB_DIGIT) )      
            board[row][column]++;            
         } // End for column       
      } // End if   
   } // End for row
} // incrementTheNeighborSquares
```

Comment: First thing, add a `cout << endl;` at the end of each row in the display function.

Comment: I added an if statement at the beginning of the for loop for ```column``` and that didn't change anything  // ```void displayTheGameBoard(int board[MAX_ROWS][MAX_COLUMNS])
{
   for (int row = 0; row < MAX_ROWS; row++)
   {
      if ( (row >= 0) && (row < MAX_ROWS) )
      {
      for (int column = 0; column < MAX_COLUMNS; column++)
      {
         if (column == MAX_COLUMNS)
         {
            cout << endl;
         }
        
```

Comment: `didn't change anything` You should now see 10 lines, which didn't happen before. Now replace `cout << currentCell;` with `cout << (int)currentCell;`. This will display the numeric values of the characters in each cell, and should give you a strong hint of where to look next.

Comment: `if (rand() % (MAX_ROWS - 3) == 0)` makes the placement of your bombs random, but you overwrite `currentCell` regardless of whether it is a bomb or not on subsequent iterations. How are you tracking which cell is the bomb and which are not? (so that information is preserved after you leave the `fillTheGameBoard()` function) Also, `if ( (row >= 0) && (row < MAX_ROWS) )` is superfluous...